# Laravel - Cannot instantiate interface

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to laravel. When i try to create an object for a normal class its throwing me the following error,

**Cannot instantiate interface**

But that class is not an interface. Its a normal class only.

Comment: Laravel uses the contracts pattern to instantiate the class you need. so you can easily change the class just by changing it in the app service provider. Check the appServiceProvider.php where it states which class is loaded by which interface. You need to use the interface in your controller and the interface will load the appropriate class.

Comment: It feels very much like there is Interface with that name

Comment: Please, provide a source code of a class you try to create.